# Генерация словаря

Tags: python, словарь, генераторы

Необходимо сгенерировать словарь, ключом которого является вершина графа, а значением кортеж с именем той же вершины и вершины, с которой она соединяется.

Словарь должен содержать названия вершин из `rnd_letters` в количестве равном длине вектора `vector_in`.

На выходе должен быть следующий результат (условно):

```
"A" : ("A","B"),
"B" : ("B","C"),
"C" : ("C","A")
```

Не могу понять как это сделать, код прилагаю.

```py
import random
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

letters = ('A', 'B', "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "K", "L")
vector_in = (2, 2, 2)
rnd_letter = list(random.sample(letters, len(vector_in)))

# connect = {
#     rnd_letter[0]: (rnd_letter[1], rnd_letter[2]),
#     rnd_letter[1]: (rnd_letter[0], rnd_letter[2]),
#     rnd_letter[2]: (rnd_letter[0], rnd_letter[1])
# }

connect = {rnd_letter[i]: tuple(rnd_letter[i] + rnd_letter[i+1]) for i in range(len(rnd_letter)-1)}

print(connect)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random

letters = ('A', 'B', "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "K", "L")
vector_in = (2, 2, 2)
rnd_letter = random.sample(letters, len(vector_in))
connect = {letter: (letter, rnd_letter[(i + 1) % len(rnd_letter)]) for i, letter in enumerate(rnd_letter)}
print(connect)
```

```
{'G': ('G', 'L'), 'L': ('L', 'D'), 'D': ('D', 'G')}
```

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ, всё заработало как надо, но не я не учёл, что в случае если в vector_in стоит двойка, то необходимо чтобы в словарь добавлялась дополнительная запись, сообщающая о том, что точка соединена с ещё одной, не могли бы вы подсказать как это реализовать, хотя бы просто наводку, если не затруднит. Код прикрепил. Спасибо за ответ.
http://pastie.org/p/57OhQ85HSnnvZPNWkT6R5s

Comment: Как должен выглядеть результат?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/gpTn2Ig6EpcC примерно вот так, но по задумке цифра в векторе должна соответствовать вершине и кол-ву ребер выходящих из неё, пусть будут четыре точки a,f,e,k и вектор (1,1,1,1) тогда граф будет как на рисунке, если бы вектор был (1,1,1,2), то точка K должна была бы соединяться с точкой F

Comment: Несколько раз перечитал, но так и не понял, что требуется. Почему в векторе единицы, если из каждой вершины выходит по 2 ребра? Почему K должна соединиться именно с F? (в данном случае других вариантов нет, а если граф 5+ вершин - с какой тогда вершиной соединять?). И вы писали "необходимо чтобы в словарь добавлялась дополнительная запись" - а привели в пример не словарь с доп. данными, а граф. Предлагаю вам сформулировать новый вопрос и в нем все предметно описать.

Comment: Насчёт вектора проглядел, действительно должно быть (2,2,2,3), если 5+ вершин тоже не понятно что делать, потому что ТЗ дали нечёткое, выглядит следующим образом: Постройте хотя бы одну реализацию заданного вектора степеней. Ни входных, ни выходных данных нет, единственное упоминание по этой теме нашёл только в книгах времён СССР, поэтому и пытаюсь что-то придумать, в любом случае, спасибо за оперативные ответы и уделённое внимание.

Answer (score 0):

```
letters = ('A', 'B', "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "K", "L")
rnd_letter = ['A', "E", "L"]
l = len(letters)


connect = {rnd_letter[i]: (rnd_letter[i], letters[(letters.index(rnd_letter[i])+1) % l]) for i in range(len(rnd_letter))}

print(connect)
```

> {'A': ('A', 'B'), 'E': ('E', 'F'), 'L': ('L', 'A')}

Используйте `%` и будет вам счастье)
А вообще лучше записать это в несколько строк, читабельнее будет

P.S.
Для учета порядка `rnd_letters`:

```
l = len(rnd_letter)
connect = {rnd_letter[i]: (rnd_letter[i], rnd_letter[(i+1)%l]) for i in range(l)}
```

Comment: Возможно не совсем понял задумку ТС, мой код учитывает порядок letters, а не rnd_letter